# PHP + Javascript parse both responses

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parsing

I have two problems. One is totally in PHP the other in Javascript. But both are equal in what I'm trying to get.

index.php

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",
    url: "insert_info.php?type=info",
    data: { array : all },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        // Returns: {'status':1}
        // I want to get "1"
        // data[0] -> doesn't work
    }
});
```

insert_info.php

```
// Connects to another file
include_once('verify_info.php');
$verify = new verify_info();

$arr = array("status:" => 1);
$extension = $verify->verify_file($_REQUEST['array'][9]);

if($extension[0] == 0){
    $arr = array("status:" => 0);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

verify_info.php

```
public function verify_file($file){
    $extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'bmp');
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    $arr = array();
    if(!in_array($info['extension'], $extensions)){
        $arr = array("status:" => 0);
    }else{
        $arr = array("status:" => 1);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

In insert_info.php, I would like to get by $extension[0] the status retrieved from the function verify_file();

After that I output as json_encode the value to Javascript and I would like, again, to parse the info.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Edit 1**: `alert(data.status);` doesn't work either.

**Edit 2:** `alert(data.status);` would never work since I echo `{'status:', 1}` (problem with that two points in the middle)
Correct way for solving the issue of javascript:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(data.status);
```

I'm still trying to get fixed the php.

**Edit 3:** All solved. Thank you guys.

```
public function verify_file($file){
    $extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'bmp');
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    if(!in_array($info['extension'], $extensions)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As i see it, `alert(data.status);` should work

Comment: set `dataType:'json'`.... inspect request in browser console network tab....need more clues as to what is sent back ( response body). Hard to tell if problem is in php, or script. ALso we have no idea what `all` is

Comment: See my edit guys, and thanks. My problem now is in PHP.

Comment: can't help without seeing what is sent

Comment: @A.Wolff You're close, his PHP line is `array("status:" => #)` so in JS you'd have to do `data["status:"]` to access it. @user3065191 It's best that you drop colons (unless necessary) from Array's you plan to convert to JSON as the colons are added via JSON and your key is "literal." If you set a key like `array("status:" => 1)` your JSON will be: `{"status:": 1}`.

Comment: @izuriel nice catch, didn't see it. I got fooled by `// Returns: {'status':1}`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, your setting your key in PHP to `"status:"` is the trailing colon necessary on the end of your key? I don't think it's necessary, PHP arrays already offer mechanisms for fetching them and your JSON will contain the string without processing it so your key once you hit your JS code will still be `"status:"` where most likely you intended for `"status"`.

Regardless of whether you will make this change or not that doesn't break anything. In your Javascript code, as @charlietfl pointed out, you should be setting the `dataType` of the return to `"json"` so you're JS Ajax call would look like:

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",
    url: "insert_info.php?type=info",
    data: { array : all },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // Assuming no change on the backend
        alert(data["status:"]);
    }
});
```

If, however, you altered the string to remove the colon then accessing the status element of data would be `data.status` as @A.Wolff pointed out in his comment. This doesn't work because of the trailing colon in the key - but accessing the data with a string key will still work.

Comment: First of all, thanks. I do already see the problem, I wrote the solution on my "Edit 2". My only problem now is on PHP side.
`$extension = $verify->verify_file($_REQUEST['array'][9]);`
Shouldn't I get $extension this way: `$extension[0]` ??

Comment: @user3065191 You're content in **Edit 2** performs the same thing that jQuery handles when setting `dataType: "json"` so it's not necessary (although it is valid). That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: @user3065191 If you're creating an associative array in PHP you need to use those keys to make it clear what you're doing: `$extension["status:"]`

Comment: Actually it was totally unecessary to have an array when I could just simple return true or false. But yet, thanks.

Comment: @user3065191 I'm glad you noticed you could simplify that - I just answered the question you asked me. Glad you're issues are resolved.